# Money Denominations

Tags: vb.net

I have payroll database, on my payroll payslip i would like to make money denominations for the salary of each employee, I.e if  an employe has got 759 Dollar then the cashier wil withdraw 7 one hundreds ,1 Fifty Dolar, 9 ten dollars from a banck
 please give me a code in vb.net

Salary  hundred  Fifty  ten

759        7        1     9

Please help me thans a lot

Comment: "plase give me the code"??? that's not how stackoverfolw works!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer in python:

```
# Target amount
amount = 759

# The denominations to be used, sorted
denoms = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1]

# Take as many of each denomination as possible
for d in denoms:
  count = amount // d
  amount -= count * d
  print "%ix%i" % (count, d)
```

Sample output:

```
7x100
1x50
0x20
0x10
1x5
4x1
```